# filter the values of dictionary items in a list by their key in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this in python:

```
x = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}, {'A': 5, 'B': 6}]
```

that its members are `Dictionary` items. I want to filter the list to get this list:

```
X = [1, 3, 5]
```

is there some kind of magical command like `x[0:2]['A']` to filter the list like this or not?

Comment: `[D['A'] for D in x]`

Comment: @El'endiaStarman thanks. that worked. could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @El'endiaStarman you could use `[D.get('A') for D in x]` to avoid key error

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Thanks for the tip! I've included it in my answer.

Comment: Did you do any research on lists or dictionaries?

Comment: @VigneshKalai - That would avoid a `KeyError`, but every time it successfully avoided such an error you'd get `None` in the list.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if that's the case then we can add an `if statement` as in your marked dupe question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
>>> y = [D['A'] for D in x]
>>> y
[1, 3, 5]
```

Also, as [Vignesh Kalai pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993353/filter-the-values-of-dictionary-items-in-a-list-by-their-key-in-python?noredirect=1#comment55742385_33993353), if you want this code to work even if the key isn't in the dictionary, use this instead:

```
[D.get('A') for D in x]
```

and then use `list(filter(bool,y))` to take out the `None`s. Like so:

```
>>> x = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}, {'A': 5, 'B': 6}, {'B': 8}]
>>> y = [D['A'] for D in x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    y = [D['A'] for D in x]
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    y = [D['A'] for D in x]
KeyError: 'A'
>>> y = [D.get('A') for D in x]
>>> y
[1, 3, 5, None]
>>> y = list(filter(bool,y))
>>> y
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to do this.

1. [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

   If you happen to do this operation more often, then prefer this way

   ```
   >>> from operator import itemgetter
   >>> get_a = itemgetter('A')
   >>> [get_a(item) for item in x]
   [1, 3, 5]
   ```

   Or with `map`

   ```
   >>> list(map(get_a, x))
   [1, 3, 5]
   ```
2. Simplest way to do this would be to use the `[]` operator, like this

   ```
   >>> [item['A'] for item in X]
   [1, 3, 5]
   ```
3. If you want to avoid the `KeyError` in dictionaries where `A` doesn't exist, you can use `dict.get`, which returns `None` by default, like this

   ```
   >>> [item.get('A') for item in X]
   [1, 3, 5]
   ```